Is Configuration Driven Development (CDD) possible in Flutter and to what extend?
The goal is to implement a Flutter application that can be configured via a JSON file (or something similar), that is being fetched at app startup.
Things I want to manage via a config file are:

App Theme
Layout of Widgets
App routing

Is that possible in Flutter, and how do I implement these things?
I already found a way to set the app theme using a JSON file, but I have no idea how to dynamically arrange widgets or configure routing.
Thank you!
I already tried creating a JSON config like this
{
    "initialRoute": "/dashboard2",
    "routes": [
        "/dashboard",
        "/dashboard2"
    ],
    "appTheme": {
        "colorScheme": {
            "seedColor": "0xffff5050"
        }
    }
}

